# Exponential Algorithm for a UISlider Control and Reverse

Tags: ios, swift, uislider, logarithm, exponential

I need a UISlider which grows exponentially, I found this code, and it works fine:

```
let steps = 10
let min: Double = 25
let max: Double = 1000

for i in 0...steps-1 {
  let value = exp(log(min) + (Double(i) / Double(steps-1)) * (log(max) - log(min)))
  print("step: \(i + 1), value: \(round(value))")
}
```

This is the output:

```
step: 1, value: 25.0
step: 2, value: 38.0
step: 3, value: 57.0
step: 4, value: 85.0
step: 5, value: 129.0
step: 6, value: 194.0
step: 7, value: 292.0
step: 8, value: 441.0
step: 9, value: 664.0
step: 10, value: 1000.0
```

It works fine, but I need the opposite formula, in order to get the "step" let's say that if I get a value of 1000, I need to get 10, if 664 get 9, and so on..

So I need the opposite formula to this in order to get the STEP:

```
let value = exp(log(min) + (Double(i) / Double(steps-1)) * (log(max) - log(min)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in 0...steps-1 {
    let val = steps - i - 1
    let value = exp(log(min) + (Double(val) / Double(steps-1)) * (log(max) - log(min)))
    print("step: \(i + 1), value: \(round(value))")
}
```